# Problematic [tags] and [tagging] tags

Tags: discussion, tags, clean-up, meta-tags

I draw your attention to [tags](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tags) and [tagging](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tagging).

Not only is one simply the verb form of applying the other (and should thus be a synonym) they certainly seem to be *meta tags*; neither could be the *only* tag on a question.

Most, but not all, seem to be for Facebook (but let me also point out the problematic [facebook-tagging](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-tagging) and [facebook-tags](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-tags), which aren't synonyms either.)

And, let's not forget [photo-tagging](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photo-tagging).

There's some clean needing doing here. And perhaps some burnination.

So, my suggested course of action:

- Synonymize [facebook-tagging](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-tagging) and [facebook-tags](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-tags) (I think the latter should be the "master")
- Clean up uses of [tags](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tags), [tagging](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tagging), and [photo-tagging](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photo-tagging) to be for the appropriate app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have cleaned up the [tagging](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tagging) & [photo-tagging](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photo-tagging) tags.

To assist with the cleanup I needed to create some new tags:

- [google-plus-tags](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-plus-tags)
- [instagram-tags](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/instagram-tags)
- [twitter-tags](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twitter-tags)
- [letterboxd-tags](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/letterboxd-tags)

I have also created a synonym to map all [facebook-tagging](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-tagging) to [facebook-tags](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-tags)

**EDIT:**

The [tags](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tags) tag has now been cleaned up too.

Comment: I'll keep chipping away at [tag:tags].

Comment: I've also started looking at the [tag:privacy] tag too...

Comment: That one is probably worthy of its own discussion.